# How to install gatsby-CLI without admin permissions on windows

Tags: javascript, npm, gatsby

I am trying to install gatsby CLI by using below npm

```
npm install --global gatsby-cli
```

and stuck with the below issue may be because I don't have admin access, anyone any idea how to get rid of this error or install gatsby globally without admin access or if I dont install globally then how to use gatsby command on CLI

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need admin access for installing global packages. However, you can install `gatsby-cli` on your local machine (where you have admin access), then `gatsby build` to generate a `public` directory. Finally, you can deploy your website by copying the `public` directory to the web server that you don't have admin access to it, for example, by using `scp`.